# how to connect mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im not sure how to get my mongodb connected and I  keep getting this error what should I change?

> server@1.0.0 start
> > node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string. Failed to connect database
Listening on PORT 5000
```

my index.js file:

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

// Importing the routes
import authRoute from "./routes/authRoute";

const app = express();

dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// All the routes
app.use("/api", authRoute);

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Database connected successfully");
})
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`${err} Failed to connect database`);
    });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// Listening to port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: console.log(process.env.DATABASE) out, make sure its value is a string. If it is `undefined`, you have not configured it to the env variable yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("err", err);
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", (err, res) => {
  console.log("MongoDB connected successfully!");
});
```